# Error: XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/home" in agular

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I am facing an issue while connecting the spring boot application with my angular application. I want to perform the get request from angular. For this, I made changes in my spring boot application by annotating the controller as @CrossOrigin.
    So far, I am able to hit the tomcat url from angular because logs in spring boot are publishing correctly. However, I am unable to fetch any response in my angular application.

````
I believe it is related to type. For simplest type-String, I had tried but no help. I am getting the below error:

```XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/home".```

Here is my spring boot:
```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    private CoronavirusDataService coronavirusDataService;

    @Autowired
    public  HomeController(CoronavirusDataService coronavirusDataService)
    {
        this.coronavirusDataService=coronavirusDataService;
    }
   @GetMapping("/home")
   public String home() throws IOException, InterruptedException, JSONException {
       String abc="Ria";
       List<LocationStats> locationStatsList= coronavirusDataService.fetchVirusData();
       //locationStatsList.stream().forEach(System.out:: println);
       //var myObj = JSON.parse('{"p": 5}');
       //return locationStatsList.toString();
       return abc;
   }
}```

Here is my angular:

```import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {CoronaData} from '../model/corona-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-corona-module',
  templateUrl: './corona-module.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./corona-module.component.css']
})
export class CoronaModuleComponent implements OnInit {

  coronaCount: CoronaData[] = [];
  coronaC: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllCases();
    console.log(this.coronaCount);
  }
  public getAllCases(){
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/home';
    this.http.get<string>(url).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.coronaC = res;
        console.log(this.coronaC);
      },
      error => {
        alert('An error has occured');
        console.log(this.coronaC);
      }
    );

  }


}```


I am quite struggling with basic, any help in this regard will be appreciated.


Thank you!
````

Comment: This is fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide an answer to your question in order to avoid unnecessary efforts of people reading this while expecting to have no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Modify my angular function with below changes:

````
 public getAllCases(){
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/home';
    this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.coronaC = res;
        console.log(this.coronaC);
      },
      error => {
        alert('An error has occured');
        console.log(this.coronaC);
      }
    );

  }```
````